# Using an Event Listener to detect clicks on buttons and then increase count on an html element

Tags: javascript, html

My main goal is to add the ability of this BlackJack game to show and increase the amount of games played at the bottom of the webpage using an Event Listener. I have only been learning JS for a few days and perhaps I picked a too difficult of problem but I am so close to a solution. Pretty sure I am either missing one variable needed or do not know about a certain function to make things easier.

I've already tried using the click function and I was able to successfully make a button that when clicked increased the amount on the button. I've also made the button and the header the same class name and it was able to successfully click the button to increase the number. But I believe I am missing something basic to connect the "debutton" class elements with the `<h4> 0 </h4>` to increase its amount.

```js
var button = document.getElementsByClassName("debutton")
var gamesplayed = document.getElementById("gamesplayed")

count = 0;
for (var i = 0 ; i < button.length; i++) {
  button[i].addEventListener('click' , displaygames , false); 
}

function displaygames() {
  console.log("The Button was clicked!");
  gamesplayed.count += 1;
  gamesplayed.innerHTML = "" + count;
};
```

```html
<body>
  <h1><b><em>BlackJack</em></b></h1>
  <h2>Betting</h2>
  <div>
    <button class="debutton" id="debutton" onClick="deal(1)">Bet  $1</button>  
    <button class="debutton" id="debutton" onClick="deal(5)">Bet $5</button>  
    <button class="debutton" id="debutton" onClick="deal(10)">Bet $10</button>  
    <button class="debutton" id="debutton" onClick="deal(20)">Bet $20</button><br> 
    <h2>My Money</h2> 
    <div id="playermoney"><b>$100</b></div>
  </div>

  <h3><em>Games Played:</em></h3>
  <h4 class="gamesplayed" id="gamesplayed" type="number">0</h4>
</body>
```

The console log is letting me know that I am finding the "debutton" elements successfully.

Comment: Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

gamesplayed.count direct access wont work following code may help

```
var count = parseInt(document.getElementById("gamesplayed").innerHTML)
count += 1;
gamesplayed.innerHTML = "" + count;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
gamesplayed.count += 1; should be count += 1
```

By the way in my opinion you don't need the listening event if you call deal() function always on debutton, then you can increment your count variable there.

Answer (score 0):

Two pointers before I go into a solution. To help understand the solution I have "dumbed" this down to its simplest form. Which is a button that updates the total counter when clicked. The second is I've used jQuery as it is a really useful tool and simplifies the work that needs to be done.

```
<button class="increase" value="10">Add</button>
<div class="total">$<span class="count">0</span></div>

<script>
    var counter = $('.total span.count');
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".increase").click(function(){
            currentValue = parseInt(counter.text())
            addValue = parseInt($(this).attr('value'));
            counter.text(currentValue + addValue);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Above we have a button that holds a value, in this case "10". We then bind a listen event for the click of the button. When clicking the button, we extract the "value" attribute and the button total value from the `span.count` element and add them together before updating the text.

Also note that I've structured it this way so the currently symbol is outside of the `span.count` element so we can trust that the value will always be numerical.

As an important note. We need to use `parseInt()` to convert the values we extract to integers. Otherwise they will be used as strings and `"10" + "10"` will result in `1010` instead of `20`.